# How to match function Expr in scala 3 macros

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, scala-macros, scala-3

With scala 3 quotes syntax:

```scala
'{...}
```

How to match a function expression?

```scala
def macroImpl(expr: Expr[T => Any])(using q: Quotes): Expr[Any] = {
 expr match {
   case '{/*how to match function here*/} => ???
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A way is:

```
def macroImpl[T : Type](expr: Expr[T => Any])(using q: Quotes): Expr[Any] = {  
    expr match {
      case '{(x : T) => ${body} : Any } => .... //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't match. There is a todo in the official docs about this. Thanks anyway.